# Connect one SD card to two devices

Tags: spi, sd-card

I have a system where an Arduino controls a DSLR camera for environmental monitoring. The Arduino can power on/off the camera and control the shutter (through the standard plug for a external shutter). The Arduino record and transmit the status of the system (battery voltaje, time of the last shot, etc.).
**I want the Arduino to be able to access the camera's SD card while the camera is powered off**. In order to check if the pictures were actually taken and check available memory (I don't need to write to the card).

So my questions are:

1. If I create a contraption to connect a single card to the camera and the arduino. The fact that the card is connected to one device (although not been used) will interfere in the operation of the other?
2. Should I consider the use of a multiplexer or something alike to completely disconnect the data lines from one device while the other is using the card?

Answer (score 1):

An SD card has two interfaces: The SPI interface is what is used by the Arduino (it is rather slow). The second one is a parallel interface, which is capable of way bigger transmission speed. It is most likely, that the camera uses that interface, since it has to transmit rather big data packets in a short time. But as I remember some pins are used for both interfaces.

We cannot know, what happens inside the camera. But providing voltage to a digital pin of a microcontroller, while it is not powered, (as it would happen, when you drive the SD card while the camera is off) can be harmful. We must assume, that this would also happen with your camera, or you risk damaging it.

Using multiplexers (or - if you find no fitting one - some simple transistors) to disconnect the camera, when you want to connect with the Arduino, seems a good idea to me. Disconnect all lines, including the supply voltage. The ground line has to stay together, though you should check with a multimeter, if the SD slot ground is the same as the shutter connector ground (if they are not, you don't want to connect these grounds). Is most likely is, but you should check it to be sure.